# How to select the indices of a price series where there is a difference of x bips?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a price series and I'd like to know the indices where there has been a change of x bips. I worked out a very ugly way to accomplish this in a loop e.g.

```
q)bips:200
q)level:0.001*bips / 0.2
q)price: 1.0 1.1 1.3 1.8 1.9 2.0 2.3
q)ix:0
q)lastix:0
q)result:enlist lastix
q)do[count price;if[abs(price[ix]-price[lastix])>level;result,:ix;lastix:ix];ix:ix+1];
q)result
  0 2 3 6
```

This is a simple O(n) algo that walks through the price series and keeps a marked index (lastix) starts from the first element until it finds a price whose difference is greater than `bips` when found saves that index and updates lastix with the one found ... is there a more idiomatic way to do it?

My if condition inside the loop is somewhat flawed don't know exactly why if I check `abs(price[lastix]-price[ix])` instead of `abs(price[ix]-price[lastix])` it doesn't give correct results.

**UPDATE:** I was aware of `deltas`but it compares consecutive elements only and that's not what I need in my OP. I apologize if the price series example in the OP was ambiguous and lead to correct results by simply using `deltas`. Here I have a counter example new prices series:

```
q)price: 1.0 1.1 1.21 1.42 1.4 1.32 1.63
q)where abs deltas price > level
,0
```

and this is not correct. The correct result which is produced by the accepted answer is still

```
0 2 3 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this maybe:

```
f:{where differ{$[level<abs[y-x];y;x]}\[x]}
```

this carries forward the last value that satisfied your condition and uses if for comparison with the [scan](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#scan) adverb, and then uses differ to pick out where the condition was satisfied and values were updated.

If I've understood your problem correctly, the same result should come from

```
newprice:1 1.1 1.3 1.8 1.9 2 2.1
```

since the final value is more than 0.2 greater than 1.8, the last value at which the level was updated.

```
q)f newprice
0 2 3 6
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: This answer produces the correct results! thank you!

Comment: Oh this solution is missing an `abs` i.e. it should be `f:{where differ{$[level<(abs y-x);y;x]}\[x]}` can you please update?
`

Comment: Ah of course, I'd misunderstood the change as an increase. Editing now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but deltas will give you the change between consectutive pairs:

```
q)deltas price
1 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.3
```

Checking for your condition returns a boolean list:

```
q)level<=deltas price
1011001b
```

Finally 'where' will return the indices:

```
q)where level<=deltas price
0 2 3 6
```

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 3):

```
level:0.001*bips:200;
result:where level<=abs deltas price:1.0 1.1 1.3 1.8 1.9 2.0 2.3;

result
0 2 3 6
```

Is this close to what you're looking for?

`Deltas` checks the difference between the current and next value, `abs` will take the absolute value, and then you're comparing each difference against "level", which you have predefine, using where to find the associated indice.

Answer (score 1):

You've included index `0` in your answer but if you want to exclude it you can use the two argument form of [`deltas`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/arith-integer/#deltas):

```
q)where level<=abs deltas[price 0;price]
2 3 6
```

Where the first argument sets the initial value to take away, in this case the first element of the `price` list.

An example of where this may be beneficial is if you were running the function for each date in a partitioned db you could pass in the last value from the previous day to ensure you didn't get the indices where there wasn't a significant difference of `bips`.